# jQuery service response showing in firebug but not loading on the browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using codeigniter. I facing an issue when accessing the data using ajax call.
This is my ajax function

```
 function getVideos(tag) {
            if (tag != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() .'xxx/xxx/videos' ?>",
                    data: {'tag': tag
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                    {                         
                        $('#list_video').html(data);

                    }    });
            }
        }
```

And this is my controller

```
 if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
      $this->load->view(/partial_view/videos', $data);
 }else{                 
       $this->template->set_template('frontend');
       $this->template->write_view('content', 'static_pages/videos', $data, TRUE);
       $this->template->render();
  }
```

When I call the function all the data  showing in firebug but not loading on the browser. I don't know what I did wrong.
My view is like this. First time shows all the videos. But it is not an ajax function. It works properly

load->view('/partial_view/videos'); ?>

Comment: Have you inspected the content of `data`?

Comment: Fixed the issue. I forgot to call the jquery plugin function for my partial view data. Thanks @DvS

Comment: Sure! Maybe share more detail so others can benefit.